# Где можно посмотреть хронологию своих вопросов-ответов?

Tags: обсуждение

О "своих" - это частности (висяки там всякие позакрывать, оценки перепоставить...).

Однако здесь есть очень интересные отвечатели и вопрошатели (например, Слава1947; просто сокровище сайта, такой энциклопедический эрудит).

Хотелось бы простого - личного кабинету - **ЛК**!

Может, что-то подобное уже существует, только я не сориентировалась?

---

Нотабене.

"Не удалось отправить ваш вопрос. Проверьте ошибки" и что-то подобное, занудно требующее исправить грамматику в теле вопроса. А где оне, ошибки-то?! О_о

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно личный кабинет существует, вот он: https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/177616/galina-avanesova?tab=questions.

Здесь вы можете просмотреть все свои сообщени и вообще историю всех действий.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

—
Насчет требованиям к грамматике — что-то странное. На сайте может быть лишь ограничение на минимальное количество символов в сообщении...

Comment: Можно ли и в какой форме лучше добавить вот сюда https://ridero.ru/books/obryvki_iz_realnostei_potegurim/ - НАД КНИГОЙ РАБОТАЛИ:
Галина Аванесова  и энтузиасты сайта https://rus.stackexchange.com/ ? ...при коллективном соучастии энтузиастов https://rus.stackexchange.com/  ? Или как?

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Это было бы очень здорово! В любой форме, которую вы считаете удобной для вас.

Comment: Nicolas, спасибо! Я, общаясь с менеджером сайта Ридеро, спросила, не будут ли они заинтересованы в нас (дала ссылки на несколько вопросов, где не стыдно за ответы). Пишу: *Инга хочет пригласить его участников глянуть на плоды нашего коллективного труда, - сайту Ридеро это никак не... интересно?

Вы сможете отправлять своих "бесплатных" авторов (а также штатных редакторов и корректоров) совещаться с коллегами-филологами в спорных/трудных случаях. У нас там и университетские выпускники водятся и даже один ВСЕСТОРОННИЙ ЭРУДИТ - slava1947!* КАК МНЕ СООБЩИТЬ ИНГИНУ БЛАГОДАРНОСТЬ ВСЕМ КТО ПОМОГАЛ?